# auto_increment in Phalcon migrations system

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, database-migration, phalcon

For some reason, the migration system is not behaving well with auto_increment primary keys. Am I overseeing something? (I'm using phalcon 2.0.1)

I have the following auto generated migration:

```
class LanguagesMigration_100 extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    $this->morphTable(
        'languages',
        array(
        'columns' => array(
            new Column(
                'id',
                array(
                    'type' => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'notNull' => true,
                    'autoIncrement' => true,
                    'size' => 11,
                    'first' => true
                )
            ),
            new Column(
                'ccode',
                array(
                    'type' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
                    'notNull' => true,
                    'size' => 6,
                    'after' => 'id'
                )
            ),
            new Column(
                'active',
                array(
                    'type' => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'notNull' => true,
                    'size' => 1,
                    'after' => 'ccode'
                )
            )
        ),
        'indexes' => array(
            new Index('PRIMARY', array('id')),
            new Index('UNIQ_A0D153794EE11504', array('ccode'))
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'TABLE_TYPE' => 'BASE TABLE',
            'AUTO_INCREMENT' => '9',
            'ENGINE' => 'InnoDB',
            'TABLE_COLLATION' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
        )
    )
    );
}
}
```

But when I run that migration, the generated sql does:

```
==> default: Phalcon DevTools (2.0.1)
==> default: 1432127144.0475
==> default: : 
==> default: SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`= 'languages' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'euromillions'
==> default:   => 
==> default: 1432127144.0619
==> default:  (
==> default: 0.014361143112183
==> default: )
==> default: 1432127144.0767
==> default: : 
==> default: DESCRIBE `euromillions`.`languages`
==> default:   => 
==> default: 1432127144.1014
==> default:  (
==> default: 0.024682998657227
==> default: )
==> default: 1432127144.1033
==> default: : 
==> default: ALTER TABLE `languages` MODIFY `id` INT(11) NOT NULL
==> default:   => 1432127144.1488 (0.045513153076172)
==> default: 1432127144.1489: ALTER TABLE `languages` ADD `active` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER ccode
==> default:   => 1432127144.17 (0.021080017089844)
==> default: 1432127144.1701: SHOW INDEXES FROM `euromillions`.`languages`
==> default:   => 1432127144.1715 (0.001410961151123)
==> default: 1432127144.1717: ALTER TABLE `languages` ADD INDEX `UNIQ_A0D153794EE11504` (`ccode`)
==> default:   => 1432127144.181 (0.0093460083007812)
==> default: 1432127144.1811: ALTER TABLE `languages` DROP INDEX `ccode`
==> default:   => 1432127144.185 (0.0038588047027588)
==> default: 1432127144.185: ALTER TABLE `languages` DROP INDEX `ccode_2`
==> default:   => 1432127144.1883 (0.0032830238342285)
==> default:                                                     
==> default:   Success: Version 1.0.0 was successfully migrated
```

As you can see, the id field is modified not including an auto_increment.

Comment: Interesting. Just to confirm, do you have this *Also is recommended to have PHP 5.4 or greater installed.*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question since it seems to be a bug in the Phalcon migrations system.

As @axalix points out, the migration is done on a table the previously existed. (I upvoted your answer because it helped me to get to the solution).

This is the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ccode` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ccode` (`ccode`),
  KEY `ccode_2` (`ccode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And this is the modified table (modified by doctrine orm:schema-tool)

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ccode` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_A0D153794EE11504` (`ccode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

It turns out that I forgot the "unsigned" option in the Doctrine entity, so when the tables was changed, the table looked like

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ccode` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_A0D153794EE11504` (`ccode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

For some reason, running the phalcon migration without the unsigned option made it to forget about the auto_increment.

I'll try to reproduce it in isolation to report the bug to the Phalcon guys.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I tried to run your migration, the table was created with auto_increment. But I see from your logs that the table is being altered (not created), what means you already had a table created earlier.

More than that, you are not adding new column `id`, but changing it `MODIFY id INT(11) NOT NULL`. So what was there before? *varchars*, non-unique values? If so, it is just impossible to add an `autoincrement` flag.

Comment: The table was there (I'm doing a transition of a legacy project to Phalcon). The only change to the table was the active column (I added it). Before, the column id was INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: From my understanding the purpose of migration is "to migrate", to apply the listed changes (not to describe what you already had). If you already had a column marked as `NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT `, there is no need to add a new Column block with *'autoIncrement' => true'*.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to have all the migrations just for the consistency purpose, that's fine, but don't expect to see in logs `AUTO_INCREMENT`, because it is already there. If you want to be sure that your migration will work well with empty database, just try it with empty database and you will see it works (I've already tested it for you).

Comment: Well, what I wanted to do is to have just the new field, and I used the  command: `phalcon migration generate --table=languages`.

What you are saying is that I shouldn't use the auto generation but to code the migrations manually?

Comment: You can use the autogeneration in order to create the initial / original migration based on the tables that you already have (1.0.0 version). And then on top of that just create manually the second migration that will add a change in the database: that will add a new column, for example.

Comment: Yes, I understand you solution. But isn't the purpose of the autogeneration to be aware of the changes and release you for doing it manually?

Comment: Sorry, can't use stackoverflow as chat